# Docbook, images already resized

Tags: xml, image, xslt, apache-fop, docbook

I have an issue with my docbook xmls. The basic problem is that I couldn't find yet any solution to keep the inline/mediaobject images original size (height/width). All of the images are displayed oversized in the PDF output.

The images have already been resized so there is no reason for defining the image size at every image. I want to keep the original size of the images.

Tools I use:
- Apache FOP v1.0
- xsltproc (cygwin)
- Docbook XSL Stylesheet (v1.76.1)

Is there any way to keep the original size of the images?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to get the original size of the image, you'd have to do something like this:

```
<mediaobject>
    <imageobject>
        <imagedata fileref="path/to/image/file" format="image_format" scalefit="1" width="100%" contentdepth="100%" />
    </imageobject>
</mediaobject>
```

The part to take note of is the **imagedata** tag with it's attribute. Please note that I used dummy values for these attributes and so you must update them to reflect your environment :D

Comment: Well, I already tried this and it doesn't have the effect what I want. I have mathml images which are basically small size (height/width) images. And I need to give a so called global "setting" to them to keep the original size.

    <inlineequation>
        <alt>\Omega</alt>
        <graphic fileref="file:///C:/fajlok/teszt2/math/eqi10.png" scalefit="1" contentdepth="48%" />
    </inlineequation>

And what about this? I have just tried it and it seems working.